# How can eigenstates of a hermitian operator be orthogonal without explicitly defining the inner product?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, definition, quantum-states

It's a well known fact that for any hermitian operator, say $H$ (assuming there is no degeneracy),  $${\left< a_i \right.\left| a_j \right> \over  \sqrt{\left< a_i \right.\left| a_i \right> \left< a_j \right.\left| a_j\right>}}=  \delta_{ij}$$

where $\left| a_i \right>$ are eigenstates (aka eigenvectors) of $H$ such that $H\left| a_i \right> = a_i \left| a_i \right>$.

My query is that, in the above result we need not define the explicit form of the inner product of the states and it seems like any definition for inner product would work. **So, is there any subtle point that I'm missing in my reasoning? or are we invoking some particular property of  the inner product that isn't obvious through the derivation of above expression?**

Any insights or comments are appreciated!

Comment: It's obvious in the literature what the definition is. It's spoken about in every intro text on QM. Why do you think otherwise?

Comment: @TobiasFünke No, not "nonsense". I think it's a valid question. OP appears to be asking if there is a general definition, which there is.

Comment: @josephh Sorry, I could've misread your comment. Do you mean [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Definition)? I think OP is confused because the text did not give an explicit realization of an inner product. But I may be wrong here.

Comment: @TobiasFünke ...yes.

Comment: I don't understand the question - there is no explicit definition of the inner product needed, the statement about eigenstates of self-adjoint operators being orthogonal holds for *all* inner products (although of course *which* operators are self-adjoint might vary with the choice of product).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My query is that, in the above result we need not define the explicit form of the inner product of the states and it seems like any definition for inner product would work.

You need a definition of inner product to know whether $H$ is Hermitian/self-adjoint or not.

---

Take the vector space $\mathbb C^2$ and consider the two inner products
$$\left<\pmatrix{a\\b},\pmatrix{c\\d}\right>_1 := \overline ac + \overline b d$$
$$\left<\pmatrix{a\\b},\pmatrix{c\\d}\right>_2 := \overline ad + \overline b c$$

**Note: the second is not actually an inner product because it is not positive definite. As a result, it does not produce a Hilbert space. However, as fixing this would add substantial algebraic clutter without meaningfully changing the answer, I have elected to keep this "mistake" intact for now.**

Let $M:= \pmatrix{w&x\\y&z}$ be a linear operator.  If we use inner product $1$ to compute its adjoint, we obtain
$$\left<\pmatrix{a\\b},M\pmatrix{c\\d}\right>_1 = \overline a\big(wc+xd\big)+\overline b\big(yc+zd\big)$$
$$= \overline{\big(\overline wa+\overline yb\big)}c + \overline{\big(\overline xa + \overline zb\big)}d = \left<M^\dagger_1\pmatrix{a\\b},\pmatrix{c\\d}\right>_1$$
$$\implies M^\dagger_1 = \pmatrix{\overline w & \overline y\\\overline x & \overline z}$$

Doing the same thing for the second inner product yields
$$\left<\pmatrix{a\\b},M\pmatrix{c\\d}\right>_2 = \overline a\big(yc+zd\big)+\overline b\big(wc+xd\big)$$
$$= \overline{\big(\overline za + \overline xb\big)}d+\overline{\big(\overline ya+\overline wb\big)}c  = \left<M^\dagger_2\pmatrix{a\\b},\pmatrix{c\\d}\right>_2$$
$$\implies M^\dagger_2 = \pmatrix{\overline z & \overline x\\ \overline y & \overline w}$$

Clearly whether $M$ is self-adjoint depends on which inner product we choose. In the former (conventional) case, $M$ is self-adjoint if its diagonal entries are real and its off-diagonal entries are complex conjugates of one another.  In the latter case, the condition for self-adjointness is that the diagonal entries are complex conjugates of one another and the off-diagonal entries are real.

The takeaway here is that when we say an operator is self-adjoint, we mean self-adjoint *with respect to a particular inner product*.  All of the subsequent properties of the operator - and in particular, the orthogonality of its eigenspaces - are with respect to the that inner product.

---

Lastly, at least for finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces, physicists essentially always use the standard inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_1$.  However, we are not missing anything by doing so.  Note that given any choice of inner product we may choose an orthonormal basis for the Hilbert space; a linear map between these bases constitutes an isometric isomorphism.

In that sense, the two Hilbert spaces which we obtain by equipping $\mathbb C^2$ with the two different inner products are equivalent.

Comment: I can honestly say that I do not recall coming across the case where the diagonal elements are complex. Examples or papers?

Comment: @josephh Are you referring to operators which are self-adjoint with respect to the second inner product?

Comment: Your answer seems to imply that operators with complex diagonal components are also self-adjoint, which seems to be a contradiction. Examples?

Comment: @josephh This is not what the answer implies. It rather gives conditions when an operator is hermitian with respect to each of the inner products.

Comment: @TobiasFünke The answer has been edited.

Comment: @josephh I edited to fix some typos, but the point remains that self-adjoint operators may have complex diagonal entries as long as the self-adjointness is with respect to the non-standard inner product $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle_2$. I added a section at the end to clarify that, although we universally use the standard inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot \rangle_1$, we aren't losing anything by doing so because the two Hilbert spaces are ultimately equivalent.

Comment: I got the answer. I was missing the point that our "usual" hermiticity i.e. $H = H^\dag$ is only for the first kind of inner product you defined. Thanks @J.Murray

Comment: @AdityaDev A hermitian operator (with respect to a chosen inner product) is represented by a hermitian matrix in an orthonormal basis (with respect to the same inner product). But if you choose to represent the operator as a matrix in a non-orthonormal basis (with respect to the former inner product), the matrix must not be hermitian, see also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3678469/hermitian-skew-hermitian-matrix-for-non-orthogonal-basis).

Comment: Right. This is probably why you refer to case 1 as "standard", since we typically use an orthonormal basis where it is a _necessary_ condition that $H=H^\dagger$

Comment: @TobiasFünke Just to clarify, the operator $M$ I wrote above is not meant to be a matrix representation with respect to any basis; rather, the array in round brackets is meant to be shorthand for the linear map $\pmatrix{a\\b}\mapsto \pmatrix{wa+xb\\ya+zb}$, and by "diagonal entries" I mean $w$ and $z$. Along the same lines, $\pmatrix{a\\b}$ is an honest element of $\mathbb C^2$, not shorthand for $a\vec v_1+b\vec v_2$ for some unspecified basis $\{\vec v_1,\vec v_2\}$.

Comment: @josephh I think we agree. Given the standard inner product, the adjoint of a matrix is given by its conjugate transpose, in which case a self-adjoint operator must have real diagonal entries.  Using a different inner product yields a different result. My intention is not to be mathematically pedantic, but rather to clarify that the orthogonality which describes the eigenspaces and the self-adjointness which describes an operator are both tied to the same (possibly unspecified) inner product - a point which the OP seems to have understood.